# How do I create a math question generator using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am basically trying to create a website that incorporates a math question generator (for grade 2 or 3 students) and when I run the code it gives me everything: the question, the check button, the output area, but whenever I put in the actual answer it always seems to tell me the answer is wrong, can someone please help me with this?

I am putting this code on a website that I have on WordPress as well.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="en">

<body>
<div id="11question"></div>
<input id="answer">
<button id="check" onclick="check()">Check</button>
</body>


<script>
num5 = 500;
num6 = 500;

var operations = {
'+': function (num5, num6) {return num5 + num6;},
'-': function (num5, num6) {return num5 - num6;},
'x': function (num5, num6) {return num5 * num6;}
}
operations = ['+','-','x'][Math.min(Math.floor(Math.random()*3))];
accans= num5 + operations +  num6;
num5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
num6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
operations = ['+','-','x'][Math.min(Math.floor(Math.random()*3))];
accans= num5 + operations +  num6;
document.getElementById("11question").innerHTML = num5 + operations + num6;

function newquestion() {
    document.getElementById('answer').value = "";
    document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor = "white";
    num5 = 500;
    num6 = 500;
    var operations = {
    '+': function (num5, num6) {return num5 + num6;},
    '-': function (num5, num6) {return num5 - num6;},
    'x': function (num5, num6) {return num5 * num6;}
    }
operations = ['+','-','x'][Math.min(Math.floor(Math.random()*3))];
    accans= num5 + operations +  num6;


    num5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    num6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    operations = ['+','-','x'][Math.min(Math.floor(Math.random()*3))];
    accans= num5 + operations + num6;


document.getElementById("11question").innerHTML = num5 + operations  + num6;
}


function check() {
    answer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
    if (accans == answer) {
        document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor = "green";
        setTimeout(newquestion, 1500);
    }
    else if (accans != answer) {
        document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor = "red";
        setTimeout(newquestion, 1500);
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've rewritten the code between the `<script>` tags so it does what you want and it's below. Here are the main things you were doing wrong:

1. You used the variable name `operations` to mean two different things: the object containing the three calculation functions, and the single operation chosen for the given calculation. I've now given the latter the name `operationChosen` so they are not overwriting each other.
2. You were not using the functions you had defined in the `operations` object to calculate the correct answer (`accans`). I've changed the calculation so it works now, using the newly defined `operationChosen`.
3. There's quite a lot of repetition. I've deleted a lot of lines that were doing the same thing. This includes that you can call `newquestion()` yourself at the start instead of writing the code creating a new question twice.
4. You were needlessly giving `num5` and `num6` initial values.

Working code:

```
var operations = {
  '+': function (num5, num6) {return num5 + num6;},
  '-': function (num5, num6) {return num5 - num6;},
  'x': function (num5, num6) {return num5 * num6;}
}
var accans

newquestion()

function newquestion() {
    document.getElementById('answer').value = "";
    document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor = "white";
    var num5 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var num6 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var operationChosen = ['+','-','x'][Math.min(Math.floor(Math.random()*3))];
    accans = operations[ operationChosen ]( num5, num6 )
    document.getElementById("11question").innerHTML = num5 + operationChosen + num6;
}

function check() {
    answer = document.getElementById('answer').value;
    if (accans == answer) {
        document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor = "green";
        setTimeout(newquestion, 1500);
    }
    else if (accans != answer) {
        document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor = "red";
        setTimeout(newquestion, 1500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Thank you! I just had one more question, how would you suggest I add a restriction that doesn't allow things like a smaller number - a greater number (i.e., 4-9)

Comment: Well, each specific restriction you want will need its own code! For that the easiest way is probably to separate the code which chooses the random numbers and the operation into their own function. You can then call that function once and then check if the function has produced an acceptable question against whatever tests you specify. If it has, display the question; if not you can call the function again in a loop until it is acceptable.

Comment: If you need more help than that then perhaps you'd be best off writing another question and posting a link to it here

Answer (score 0):

```js
var num1, num2, operator
const operations={
  "+":["+",(n,m)=>(n*1)+(m*1)], //*1 to prevent 1+1=11
  "-":["-",(n,m)=>n-m],
  "*":["x",(n,m)=>n*m]
}
const o=Object.keys(operations)

function newQuestion(){
  document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor=""
  num1=Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)
  num2=Math.ceil(Math.random()*10)
  operator=o[Math.floor(Math.random()*o.length)]
  document.getElementById('11question').innerText=num1+operator+num2
}

function check(){
  var answer=document.getElementById('answer')
  if(operations[operator][1](num1,num2)==answer.value){answer.style.backgroundColor = "green"}
  else{answer.style.backgroundColor = "red"}
  setTimeout(newQuestion,1500)
}

newQuestion()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html lang="en">

<body>
<div id="11question"></div>
<input id="answer" type="number">
<button id="check" onclick="check()">Check</button>
</body>

</html>
```